# How to create p2p metalinks files

Tags: linux, bittorrent, file-download, p2p, magnet-links

[Metalinks files are files which allows to download files or folder using multiple protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalink).

There are lot of softwares for downloading using MetaLink. But in my case, I want to create a metalink file for a local folder containing over 100000 files. The resulting metalink should allows to download the files through torrent or magnet (which means the magnet links should be generated in the process).

I only found dir2ml, which create metalinks from ftp paths without p2p protocols support for download.

Comment: *"I only found dir2ml"* - There are a number of applications listed in the [Metalink generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalink#Metalink_generation) section of the Wikipedia article you cited. Have you tried those applications and, if so, what were the results? What is the issue you are encountering regarding the number of files?

Comment: @Anaksunaman they are very old. The links aren t up to date or the applications no longer works with current download software.